# Ошибка вывода в файл

Tags: java, файлы

Подскажите, пожалуйста, в чем ошибка? Файл создается но он пустой, а массив которым заполняю точно не пустой.

```
try {
        File file = new File("/home/SYSVOL/users/6-значные.txt");
    FileWriter wr = new FileWriter(file);
    for(int i=0;i<passw.length;i++)
    {
    wr.write(passw[i]);
    }
    }
    catch(Exception e)
     {
     System.out.println(e);
     }
```

Comment: А где завершение вопроса?

Answer (score 3):

Не забываем закрывать файл после записи.

```
wr.close();
```

Comment: Спасибо!Заработало!

Comment: Иногда еще рекомендуется очищать буфер записи через `wr.flush()`, тогда файл будет "проявляться" постепенно.